# Question with airflow using. My DAG work well and fast with dags test in terminal but keep running all time with manual trigger

Tags: python, airflow

The problem I meet is I set a PythonOperator and use subprocess module to call a sub process.
After trigger it manually in airflow UI I search ffmpeg process with top -pid and find ffmpeg process is sleeping.
So why can be that?

I run airflow with command

```
airflow standalone
```

and run on my MacBook Air with M1.
I config airflow with LocalExecutor and PostgreSQL.
My airflow version is v2.6.1 and Python version is 3.7.16 .

It can show success when sending simple command like "ls" or "ffmpeg -version" or "sleep 5", but the task will keep running status and never be finished when I try to send complex command like use ffmpeg to convert from .avi video to .mp4 video. But this dag runs well in terminal with command

```
airflow dags test example
```

and it can be finished fast.

Here is my code.

```
from __future__ import annotations

# [START tutorial]
# [START import_module]

# import sys
import os
from airflow.operators.python import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
import subprocess
import shutil
input_dir = "/Users/lll/airflow/video_input/"
output_dir = "/Users/lll/airflow/video_output/"

# import json
# from textwrap import dedent

import pendulum

# The DAG object; we'll need this to instantiate a DAG
from airflow import DAG

# Operators; we need this to operate!
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

# [END import_module]

# [START instantiate_dag]
with DAG(
    "ffmpeg_example",
    # [START default_args]
    # These args will get passed on to each operator
    # You can override them on a per-task basis during operator initialization
    default_args={
        "retries": 2,
    },
    # [END default_args]
    description="cut video into frame and add watermarks",
    schedule=None,
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["ffmpeg"],
) as dag:
    # [END instantiate_dag]
    # [START documentation]
    dag.doc_md = __doc__
    # [END documentation]

    # count files
    def count_func():
        file = open("/Users/lll/airflow/debug1.log", "a")
        file.write("start\n")
        file.close()
        # get files list
        file_list = os.listdir(input_dir)
        cnt = 0
        for item in file_list:
            # mark and count
            if os.path.isfile(input_dir+item):
                cnt += 1
                os.rename(input_dir+item, input_dir+"inWorking"+str(cnt)+item)

    # switch
    def switch_func(lowerLimit: int, UpperLimit: int) -> str:
        cnt = 0
        file_list = os.listdir(input_dir)
        for item in file_list:
            if "inWorking" in item:
                cnt += 1
        if cnt < 10:
            return "less"
        else:
            return "more"
        
    # convert to mp4
    def convert_to_mp4_func(item: str, output_path: str) -> bool:
        if item[-3:] == "mp4":
            shutil.copy(input_dir+item, output_path+item)
            return True
        target = item.split('.')[0] + ".mp4"
        command = [
            "ffmpeg",
            # "-version",
            "-i", input_dir+item,
            "-c:v", "libx264",
            "-c:a", "mp3",
            "-y",
            "-strict", "experimental",
            output_path+target,
            # "ls"
        ]
        try:
            file = open("/Users/lll/airflow/debug1.log", "a")
            file.write("convert cmd run\n")
            file.close()
            subprocess.check_output(command)
            file = open("/Users/lll/airflow/debug1.log", "a")
            file.write("convert cmd run\n")
            file.close()
            return True
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print("convert failed:", e)
            return False

    # change video to frames
    def video_to_frame(item: str, input_path:str, output_path: str) -> bool:
        file = open("/Users/lll/airflow/debug1.log", "a")
        file.write("framing\n")
        file.close()
        prefix = item.split('.')[0]
        command = [
            "ffmpeg",
            # "-version",
            "-i", input_path+item,
            "-f", "image2",
            "-y",
            output_path+prefix+"%03d.png",
            # "sleep", "5"
        ]
        try:
            file = open("/Users/lll/airflow/debug1.log", "a")
            file.write("frame cmd run\n")
            file.close()
            subprocess.check_output(command)
            file = open("/Users/lll/airflow/debug1.log", "a")
            file.write("frame cmd end\n")
            file.close()
            return True
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print("cut into frame failed:", e)
            return False

    # watermark
    def add_watermark(item: str, input_path:str, output_path: str) -> bool:
        file = open("/Users/lll/airflow/debug1.log", "a")
        file.write("watermarking\n")
        file.close()
        file_list = os.listdir(input_path)
        prefix = item.split('.')[0]
        for cur_it in file_list:
            if prefix in cur_it:
                command = [
                    "ffmpeg",
                    # "-version",
                    "-i", input_path+cur_it,
                    "-y",
                    "-vf", "drawtext=fontfile=./tmp/msyhbd.ttc:fontsize=200:x=(w - 10 - text_w):y=10:fontcolor=white:text='lyb':shadowx=4:shadowy=4:alpha=0.5",
                    output_dir+cur_it,
                    # "ls"
                ]
            try:
                subprocess.check_output(command)
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                print("cut into frame failed:", e)
                return False
        return True

    # worker
    def manual_video_func(index: int, cnt: int):
        # get files list
        file_list = os.listdir(input_dir)
        for item in file_list:
            if "inWorking" in item:
                temp = ""
                i = 9
                while i < len(item) and item[i] >= '0' and item[i] <= '9':
                    temp += item[i]
                    i += 1
                num = int(temp)
                # if cur worker
                if num % cnt == index:
                    temp_dir_mp4 = input_dir+"mp4/"
                    os.makedirs(temp_dir_mp4, exist_ok=True)
                    # convert to mp4
                    # file.write("start mp4")
                    if convert_to_mp4_func(item, temp_dir_mp4) != True:
                        raise AirflowException("convert to mp4 failed!")
                    # file.write("finish mp4")
                    # to frames
                    target = item.split('.')[0]+".mp4"
                    temp_dir_pic = input_dir+"pic/"
                    os.makedirs(temp_dir_pic, exist_ok=True)
                    if video_to_frame(target, temp_dir_mp4, temp_dir_pic) != True:
                        raise AirflowException("convert to frame failed!")
                    # add watermark
                    if add_watermark(item, temp_dir_pic, output_dir) != True:
                        raise AirflowException("add watermark failed!")
                    os.makedirs(input_dir+"test")
        

    # finish
    def finish_func():
        file = open("/Users/lll/airflow/debug1.log", "a")
        file.write("end\n")
        file.close()
        file_list = os.listdir(input_dir)
        for item in file_list:
            # chean
            if os.path.isfile and "inWorking" in item:
                os.remove(input_dir+item)
            else:
                shutil.rmtree(input_dir+item)

    
    count_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="count",
        python_callable=count_func,
    )

    switch_task = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id="switch",
        python_callable=switch_func,
        op_args=[0, 10],
    )

    less_task = EmptyOperator(
        task_id="less",
    )

    more_task = EmptyOperator(
        task_id="more",
    )

    worker_task_0_0 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="worker_0_0",
        python_callable=manual_video_func,
        op_args=[0, 2],
    )

    worker_task_0_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="worker_0_1",
        python_callable=manual_video_func,
        op_args=[1, 2],
    )

    worker_task_1_0 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="worker_1_0",
        python_callable=manual_video_func,
        op_args=[0, 5],
    )

    worker_task_1_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="worker_1_1",
        python_callable=manual_video_func,
        op_args=[1, 5],
    )

    worker_task_1_2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="worker_1_2",
        python_callable=manual_video_func,
        op_args=[2, 5],
    )

    worker_task_1_3 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="worker_1_3",
        python_callable=manual_video_func,
        op_args=[3, 5],
    )

    worker_task_1_4 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="worker_1_4",
        python_callable=manual_video_func,
        op_args=[4, 5],
    )

    more_complete_task = EmptyOperator(
        task_id="more_completed",
    )

    less_complete_task = EmptyOperator(
        task_id="less_completed",
    )

    finish_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="finish",
        python_callable=finish_func,
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED_MIN_ONE_SUCCESS,
    )

    count_task >> switch_task >> [less_task, more_task]
    less_task >> [worker_task_0_0, worker_task_0_1] >> less_complete_task
    more_task >> [worker_task_1_0, worker_task_1_1, worker_task_1_2, worker_task_1_3, worker_task_1_4] >> more_complete_task
    [less_complete_task, more_complete_task] >> finish_task
```

Comment: can u please share the dag and the PythonOperator code? 10x

Comment: I add my code to this question.

Comment: try to run with "shell=True" . subprocess.check_output(command,  shell=True)

Comment: After add "shell=True", it still keep running and ffmpeg process is sleeping. It stopped at line "subprocess.check_output(command)", and debug1.log end with "convert cmd run".

Comment: My code work with airflow running with docker, so it is no problem with my code. It must be something wrong with airflow on my mac.